# How to write Java TestNG test class for scala play framework project?

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, playframework, testng

I'm new to Scala, Is it possible to write test classes using TestNG with Java. Could anyone help me on this? It seems typical for me and always getting compilation exception while calling Scala controller from Java test classes.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://github.com/linkedin/play-testng-plugin?

Comment: @lippertsjan thank you.

Comment: @Sahish You may want to accept the answer I've given below as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [TestNG plugin](https://github.com/linkedin/play-testng-plugin) for the Play!-framework which enables you to write TestNG test classes.

(Converted from comment to answer)